# How can I load res_odbc.so

Tags: asterisk

I want to load res_odbc.so but not have res_odbc.so in /etc/lib/asterisk/modules
I understand, I should select res_odbc when install asterisk
but can not select it

make menuselect
[XXX] res_odbc

Why I can't select it
I installed Asterisk 1.8, CentOS
I already installed ODBC.

What should I do? Help me please.

T_T

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you have the related devel packages installed, as well.

```
# yum install unixODBC unixODBC-devel libtool-ltdl libtool-ltdl-devel
```

Once you have done that, be sure to re-run the Asterisk configure script.  Then check menuselect and res_odbc should be available.

```
# ./configure
# make menuselect
```

The [Relational Database Integration](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596517342/asterisk-DB.html) chapter of "Asterisk: The Definitive Guide" covers this topic in more detail.