# res_odbc.so not found - Asterisk

Tags: linux, dynamic, odbc, centos, libraries

I have similar problem like here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835551/how-can-i-load-res-odbc-so/15679121#15679121)

In my case I have selected in menuselect res_odbc

```
[*] 1.res_adsi
[*] 2.res_agi
[*] 3.res_clioriginate
[*] 4.res_config_odbc
XXX 5.res_config_pgsql
[*] 6.res_convert
[*] 7.res_crypto
[*] 8.res_features
[*] 9.res_indications
XXX 10. res_jabber
[*] 11. res_monitor
[*] 12. res_musiconhold
[*] 13. res_odbc
[*] 14. res_smdi
XXX 15. res_snmp
[*] 16. res_speech
```

When I try to load:

```
PBX*CLI> module load res_odbc.so
[Mar 28 11:17:27] WARNING[2216]: loader.c:363 load_dynamic_module: Error loading module 'res_odbc.so': /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_odbc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Mar 28 11:17:27] WARNING[2216]: loader.c:657 load_resource: Module 'res_odbc.so' could not be loaded.
```

...but I had installed Asterisk before I installed ODBC in Centos. Should I re-compile Asterisk? How to do it? Just #make install?

Will my configurations files (or antythink from Asterisk) be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not asterisk-related. It ralated to dynamic libraries path in linux.

Please do following:

```
ldd /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_odbc.so
```

Check in output missing libraries. After that find that libraries in path, add that path to /etc/ld.so.conf and do

```
ldconfig
```

Most likly you have add /usr/local/lib/ path.